# Is it possible to create proxy type of integer?

Tags: c#, .net, clr

That was just a test I tried. I want to make a type which behaves exactly like `int`. I tried to make a proxy type like this:

```
class myint : int { }
```

but then `myint` won't be value type. Is there a way to create a proxy type of `int`?

P.S. I know about extension methods.

Comment: You could extend Int32 though couldn't you? What is it you are actually trying to achieve?

Comment: @KingCronus - How would you extend the `Int32` structure?

Comment: Ignore me. I was having a dumb moment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Value types can only implement interfaces - you can't inherit from another value type.

So, you can't inherit from `int`.

You *can* wrap an `int` in a class/struct as a field.